# I supplied 220 volts to 120 volts FM radio receiver?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power-electronics, frequency-modulation

I mistakenly plug an FM radio receiver of 120 volts directly to my home electricity : 220 volts. it worked for almost 5 seconds and then something inside got fried and it stop working.

Do you have any idea which component may be fried or It's entirely broken ??

Comment: Look on the bright side. Last time I did that I didn't even get 5 seconds of working time. I got a puff of smoke and the circuit breaker tripped cutting the power to the whole room. It didn't even stay on long enough to blow the fuse in the plug.

Comment: Time to buy a new radio, one rated for 220V. Repair questions are generally off topic on EE.SE.

Comment: Find a local electronics hobbyist. Tell him or her what happend to your radio, and ask if they want to try to fix it. I'm sure they'll appreciate the gift.

Answer (score 6):

Excuse me for this slightly sarcastic comment, but:

No, you cannot revive your radio parrot:

[image: Parrot, being tired after having an extended squat on a 220V line]

Well, you connected something to a voltage supply twice as high as it was meant to be used with. If you're lucky, only the parts of the radio "closest" to the connector have been fried – in an optimal case, there's simply a fuse that has blown.

More realistically, since the thing stopped working after 5 seconds: Something more intricate got thermally overloaded, and then failed, very likely taking more parts with it to its warm grave. So, unless this is an antique or really HiFi component, get another FM radio. Identification and replacement of broken parts, if at all possible, is not economically feasible.

Comment: He's dead, Jim.

Comment: @TomCarpenter [indeed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MH7KYmGnj40)

Comment: And it's doing things in Denver.

Comment: **[Insert sarcastic comment about world's smallest violin here]**